# Closing an XAML form

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I am creating a windows 8 store application using **vs2012**.
I am tying to switch to another **xaml** form by click of a button but cannot do it.
I want the code to close or hide the current form and to switch over to new form .
Regards

Comment: give us some code. What did you try ? What do you have atm ?

Comment: i am a newbie.. I tried to use this.hide() but i was unable to do so.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to wholesale replace the content then you can use the Frame.Navigate() method.

```
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(YourPageClass));
```

or simply

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(YourPageClass));
```

Answer (score 0):

remember that not every elemet has property hide or something like that. If you want to hide a grid with form or do a simillar thing you need to know the property that is responsible for visibility (in most cases it is Visibility and it is a bool).

The second thing is that you can be a newbie but if you want help make some effort and give us what you want

The third thing. If you want to change a page after click use Marc`s solution